# Why would $(x+1)$ transform the graph to the left?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, transformation

> Why do transformations for the $x$ variable in graphs work opposite as you would expect?

Example: $f(x) =(x)-1$ moves the graph down as you would expect but $g(x) = (x+1)-1$ moves the graph down (as it looks like) but instead of to the right one it's to the left one.

Note: I understand fully how to do graph transformations but don't understand why we just deem the x-value transformations as "doing the opposite".
Thanks!

Comment: What happens at $x=0$ will now happen at $x=-1.$

Comment: "*Opposite how you'd expect*" is subjective.

Comment: A more intuitive explanation is that the transformation $f(x + 1)$ means that the **coordinate axes** are what are actually shifting to the **right** $1$ while the graph stays in place. This causes the *graph* to appear like it shifted to the *left* $1$ instead. This logic also happens with the vertical shift $y = f(x) + 4$, but only if we move the vertical shift to be with the $y$: i.e., $y - 4 = f(x)$ implies the entire **coordinate axes** moves **down** $4$, causing the *graph* to move *up* $4$.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the objects in front of yourself. Now take a step to the right. The objects shifted to the left, not right, right?

Answer (score 0):

Because your domain values will decrease by $1$ in order to provide the same output.
Let’s say for $f(x)$, we have the following points:
$$(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), (x_3, y_3)$$
Now, if we have $f(x+1)$, our inputs will all decrease by one.
$$(x_1-1, y_1), (x_2-1, y_2), (x_3-1, y_3)$$
Obviously, the $-1$ balances the $+1$ in $f(x+1)$.
Therefore, this explains why we carry out the opposite operation to those in the parentheses. In a more general form, we get the following rule.

For positive values of $n$, shift $n$ units left for $f(x+n)$ and shift $n$ units right for $f(x-n)$.

For multiplication and division within the parentheses, the idea is exactly the same.

For values of $n$, there will be horizontal stretch by scale factor $\vert{\frac{1}{n}}\vert$ for $f(nx)$, and there will be horizontal stretch by scale factor $\vert n\vert$ for $f(\frac{x}{n})$.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to notice is that in an equation like

$$y=(x+1)^2 - 2$$

the 1 is with the $x$, but the $-2$ is on the opposite side
of the equal sign from $y$.  This $-2$ moves the graph down,
but put it on the other side of the equation and you have

$$y+2 = (x+1)^2.$$

So things are more symmetric than you thought.  Pluses move things in the negative direction.

Next, if you think of a graph drawing machine that's going to draw the graph of $y=f(x)$ from left to right, then what happens when you increase $x$ by $1$?  Everything happens 1 unit sooner.  $x$ may be at $7$, but the function is being fed $8$, so the point that used to be at $8$ is now at $7$.  Everything is shifted left.